# How can I send Numpad Keys through my program

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to create a program that presses Numpad 0 in the program, every few set seconds. This is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int enabled = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (enabled == 0)
            {
                Start.Text = "Stop";
                Timer.Enabled = true;
                enabled = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Start.Text = "Start";
                Timer.Enabled = false;
                enabled = 0;
                label2.Text = "0";
            }

        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{NumpadIns}");
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this so far

```
{NumpadIns}
{NumIns}
{Num0}
{INS}
```

Nothing seems to work, the program I'm using with it is bound to Num Zero so it has to be Num Zero and not 0 on the top row, or Insert. Thanks (Yes I have googled but for some reason this is really hard to find).

Comment: Your program has to have the focus for this to work.  Only the window having the focus can receive keystrokes using SendKeys.

Comment: Have you tried `{NUMPAD0} - {NUMPAD9}`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should you some wrappers like [Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). It is easy to use and have many pre-defined enums so you do not need to pass String argument.

Comment: Input Simulator is meant for sending keys to other applications.